# The keyboard behaves strangely in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard

im using ubuntu 22.04.

Suddenly, while typing, different keyboard keys were connected to the media keys and the keyboard mapping got messed up.

a and esc Buttons pause the video.

The right shift has the same function as Caps Lock

The left shift has the same function as F1.

shift+a not capitalize but for other works fine.

in other layout have same problem. on other distro have same problem.

What is the problem and how do fix it?

Comment: Let me guess: Asus notebook?

Comment: @matigo no - acer

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked in the system -> preferences -> keyboard, under the layout tab....?

Try this https://techwiser.com/fix-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I think it's the appropriate link i have shared here.